# list of arguments to python function

Tags: python, function, arguments

Is there a way to build a list of the arguments to python function to use it inside the function?
For example:

```
def sum_of_middle_three(score1,score2,score3,score4,score5):
"""
Find the sum of the middle three numbers out of the five given.
"""
sum = (score1+score2+score3+score4+score5)
return sum
```

How to refer to the input argument list in the function, if possible this gives possibility to call that function by variable argument list

Answer (score 2):

You can use `*args` and `**kwargs`

`*args` and `**kwargs` allow you to pass a variable number of arguments to a function.

Example:

```
In [3]: def test(*args):
   ...:         return sum(args)
   ...:
   ...:

In [4]: test(1, 2, 3, 4)
Out[4]: 10

In [5]:
```

Addtionally if you want to preserve name of the argumenets use `**kwargs`,

Example:

```
In [10]: def tests(**kwargs):
    ...:     print(kwargs)
    ...:     return sum(kwargs.values())
    ...:
    ...:

In [11]: tests(a=10, b=20, c=30)
{'a': 10, 'c': 30, 'b': 20}
Out[11]: 60

In [12]:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*args`

```
def f(*args):
    return(sum(args))

>>>f(1,2,3,4)
10

>>>f(1,2)
3
```